# Access original keybinding for a mode after re-definition

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

I'm running into an odd case for rebinding keys, and I'm not sure of the solution. Basically, I want to replace a bunch of keybindings and move the original definition for each to a different key. Here's what I have so far:

```
(mapc (lambda (map)
          (define-key map "K" (lookup-key map "k"))
          (define-key map "k" #'<my new command for "k">)
        (list <a bunch of mode maps>))
```

The bad part is `lookup-key`: it will work fine on the first evaluation, but if I re-evaluate it will rebind "K" to my new binding for "k". So, my question is, is there a way to look up the **original** binding for a keymap? (Basically, I think I'm looking for the equivalent of `noremap` in vim.)

Comment: Why not just check if `"k"` is already bound to `new command` in `map` and do nothing in this case ?

Comment: @politza that seems like the simplest solution, if you make that an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to maintain your own data structure of modified keys and their original key bindings. So at the time you define the new binding, you also store the current binding somewhere.

That is how [bind-key](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el) (part of `use-package`) implements its  `describe-personal-keybindings` command, which shows you all the bindings you have created along with their original bindings.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as "the original binding". But you can save the binding at any point, including just after starting an Emacs session. That might be "original" enough for you; dunno.

And yes, as @glucas points out, functions such as `define-key` act like assignments (e.g., like `setq`). If you want to later revert to some previous value then you will need to have saved that value and then reassign to it later.

Note too that if you know the command currently bound to a key (finding it using `lookup-key` or in some other way), you can use `(define-key [remap ORIG-COMMAND] 'NEW-COMMAND)` to remap **all** keys bound to that `ORIG-COMMAND` to your `NEW-COMMAND`.

You can later restore **all** of those keys to their original bindings to `ORIG-COMMAND` by simply using `(define-key [remap ORIG-COMMAND] nil)`, that is, by making that remapping undefined (binding a key to `nil` makes it undefined).

Comment: Cool - I didn't realize you could remove a `[remap..]` binding that way.

Comment: Interestingly, `setq` and friends *do* keep track of the original value as part of the `customize` machinery. I was wondering if there was some similar thing for keybindings, but I guess not.

Comment: @shosti: Nonsense. It is Customize, not `setq` that does that. And Customize records initial values etc. only for **options**, not variables in general. And if you use `setq` more than once, even on an option, there will be *no history of previous values* (other than the last saved and initial default values).

Comment: @Drew right, I meant when you setq a customizable option. The point stands.

Comment: @shosti: It doesn't stand, even in that case, if your point is that Customize keeps track of past assignments. It does not. It keeps track of only the initial/default and the last saved. It does not keep a history of settings.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what or why you're arguing here (no one said anything about tracking history, just original values). In any case, the answer to the original question is "no", let's leave it at that :)

Comment: @shosti: My bad - you did say "*original values*". My point about `define-key` being like `setq` was that neither keeps track of the previous value, before the "assignment". And yes, there is no Customize equivalent for `define-key`, which, yes, records the original value. (But you can arrange to use Customize also for keys that you bind, which will give you that effect.)